# Which is best approach to use background images? Shorthand property or default properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Which is best approach to use background images? Shorthand property or default properties?

Comment: I think this is largely opinion-based, but for what it's worth, I find the shorthand methods less readable compared to the 'normal' way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but am little bit worry about older browsers and Modern browsers IE etc does they support the short-hand property?

Comment: You shouldn't have an issue with browser support, so it's up to you to decide which method you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me about this confusion

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer shorthand as it makes your stylesheet look a lot cleaner. When you are starting out with CSS, probably the default is better but once you get familiar with CSS, I'd suggest the shorthand.

After all we humans are lazy. Shorthand properties -> Lesser code -> cleaner & easier maintenance of stylesheets -> happier life!

Comment: I was just thinking about browsers compatibility. I mean short-Hand Properties might create problems while we rub our code in Older browsers like IE version of browsers? What do you think is there a problem of cmpatibility.??? With short-hand properties instead of Normal use of Backgrounds.....

Comment: As far as I'm aware, short-hand and doesn't have compatibility issues.
[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties
) docs encourages us to use shorthand.

Once you start writing CSS on a  regular basis, you'll come across [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) which again encourage short hand!!

Answer (score 0):

This is waht i think is the best way of using a picture background, i used it several times. I do not take credit fro it full credit goes out to https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link I read that article and Cleared my all confusions about browsers compatibility.